# Uploading .sql to phpAdmin error

Tags: php, asp.net, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I wrote my website in asp.net and was trying to host it with hostgator but i cant seem to sucessfully upload my database. I downloaded sql server management studio (2008 cuz my computer is old) and generated a script and uploaded it in the import section of php admin. it said it was successful but it gave me this error and none of my tables or anything are there when i refreshed it.

```
  USE [master]
    GO

    /****** Object: Database [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] Script Date: 04/08/2014 17:29:07 ******/
    CREATE DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] ON PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_af4ae78d33fc4895ba88828a794ca99a_DAT', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' , SIZE = 10240KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5120KB )
    LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_TMP_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 768KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    GO

    ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
    GO

    IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
    begin
    EXEC [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\D[...]
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 208
STR: :\
SQL: USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF]    Script Date: 04/08/2014 17:29:07 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_af4ae78d33fc4895ba88828a794ca99a_DAT', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' , SIZE = 10240KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5120KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_TMP_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 768KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_CLOSE ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET  READ_ONLY 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET PAGE_VERIFY NONE  
GO

ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO




SQL query:

USE [master] GO /****** Object: Database [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] Script Date: 04/08/2014 17:29:07 ******/ CREATE DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] ON PRIMARY ( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_af4ae78d33fc4895ba88828a794ca99a_DAT', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' , SIZE = 10240KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5120KB ) LOG ON ( NAME = N'ASPNETDB_TMP_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 768KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%) GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100 GO IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) begin EXEC [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable' end GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ARITHABORT OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_CLOSE ON GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT GLOBAL GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET DISABLE_BROKER GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET READ_ONLY GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET RECOVERY FULL GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET MULTI_USER GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET PAGE_VERIFY NONE GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\WEBSITE5\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF] SET DB_CHAINING OFF GO

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [C:\USERS\SCRIBBLENAUT.OWNER-PC\DOCUME' at line 1
```

it says the error is on line one which seems a bit ridiculous to me. I dont think there is anything wrong with my query since it's generated. Anyone have any ideas? I really need this to work. I've spent over 3 months building this website and it's nothing without the database!

Comment: You have spaces in your file path, this will throw an error.

Comment: SQLServer databases do not import to a MySQL server. They are different databases. The syntax is different.

Comment: @Vector I just tried that. Same error

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you tell me how i can change it to a MySql database then?

Comment: Try a few searches, this also may help you get started http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/need-to-migrate-sql-server-to-mysql

Comment: Actually MySQL Workbench which is free has a migration tool in the toolkit. I have never used it, but its free and worth a try.

Comment: You use SQL server, right? If you have problem, please just upload your full .bak file and ask them to restore it for you.